# Обрезка пустых пикселей

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. 
Есть много *.png изображений с прозрачным фоном, мне нужно обрезать пустые пиксели вокруг самой картинки и сохранить при этом прозрачность под картинкой. вот на пример есть картинка, по центру кубик 5x5px, общий размер изображения 10x10px из-за того что вокруг кубика пустые пиксели. так вот мне нужно сделать обрезку чтобы он убрал все лишние пиксели и оставил только кубик по центру. подобная функция есть в фотошопе "свободное выделение", он выделяет только объект прямоугольной формой. изображений много и фотошопить не лучший вариант. возможно ли такое на php?

Comment: В фотошопе есть возможность пакетной обработки (ну по крайней мере в 2007-2008б, когда я его использовал, было). На примере одной картинки задаете, потом указываете где искать остальные картинки и идете пить чай/кофе.

Если есть желание на php, то посмотрите в сторону библиотеки ImageMagick. Она умеет делать crop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написал [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim), ImageMagick умеет делать обрезку по-умному: начиная с краёв исходного изображения, идет к центру, пока не встретит пиксели, отличные по цвету/прозрачности от тех, что по краям. Предполагается, что по краями все пиксели идентичны.

Поэтому ваша задача решается в два шага:

1. дорисовать вокруг изображения рамку из прозрачных пикселей, чтобы наверняка они все были одинаковы;
2. обрезать их "автомагически".

ImageMagick есть и как библиотека для PHP, и как [отдельные утилиты](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php), которые можно запускать из командной строки. В данном случае поможет [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php), примерно так:

```
convert INPUT.PNG -bordercolor none -border 10 INPUT_BORDERED.PNG
convert INPUT_BORDERED.PNG -trim +repage OUTPUT.PNG
```

В php-варианте смотрите [`borderImage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/imagick.borderimage.php) и [`trimImage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/imagick.trimimage.php).

Comment: Это уже другой отдельный вопрос. Но попробуйте просто скачать их command line tools.